# Django: Passing the result of {% trans %} via a filter

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a string that I want passed via the "linebreaks" filter.

```
{% trans "my string"|linebreaks %}
```

Doesn't work.

Is there another way ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See [`filter`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#filter).

```
{% filter force_escape|lower %}
    {% blocktrans %}This text will be translated, HTML-escaped, and will appear in all lowercase.{% endblocktrans %}
{% endfilter %}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you need to filter before translation, you can also use:

```
{% blocktrans with value|filter as myvar %}
This will have {{ myvar }} inside.
{% endblocktrans %}
```

Comment: The above does not translate "value". It only appears to translate the full string inside the {% blocktrans %}.

What I need is a filter applied to the translation's result

Comment: well so i said, "filter before" :)